# In Javascript how to check if a class was loaded before?

Tags: javascript

I load a JS class using ajax

so this method will get Car as class name and load it

```
function loadClass(className ){
$.ajax({
  url: className +".js",
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
}
```

js can contain for example

```
class Car {
  constructor(brand) {
    this.carname = brand;
  }
 }
```

How can i check if class already loaded because running the function multiple times it will result in:

```
SyntaxError: redeclaration of let Car
```

Comment: Save the value of `className` to an array, then check to see if it is in the array before you make the request...

Comment: this is my last option, im sure there is a way to try to instantiate it or look it up

Comment: Test if `window.Car` is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use several approaches. You can write a decorator function for loadClass that will "remember" which classes already have been loaded:

```
function runFnJustOnce(fn) {
    let memory = {};

    return function(...args) {

        let key = JSON.stringify(args);

        if (!memory[key]) {
            memory[key] = fn(...args) || true;
        }

        return memory[key];
    }
}

function loadClass(className ){
    $.ajax({
        url: className +".js",
        dataType: "script",
        success: success
    });
}

loadClass = runFnJustOnce(loadClass);
```

Or, simpler stuff like:

```
let { Car } = window;
Car || loadClass("Car");

typeof Car === undefined ? loadClass(Car) : "Already loaded";
```

Or:

```
typeof Car === undefined ? loadClass(Car) : "Already loaded";
```

Or:

```
let className = "Car";
window[className] ? "Already loaded" : loadClass(className);
```

Or:

```
try {
    {[Car]:Car}
    //Already loaded;
} catch (e) {
    loadClass("Car");
}
```

Or many other approaches ...

Answer (score 5):

Check if the class name is defined as a global variable.

```js
function loadClass(className) {
  if (typeof window[className] == 'undefined') {
    $.getScript(className + ".js", success)
  }
}
```

This doesn't actually check if the name is defined as a class, but I don't think that's important -- you should probably avoid redefining any global name.

Comment: would it be better: `if(typeof window[className] == 'undefined')`?

Comment: yeah, changed it

Comment: Answer is working fine, but ill accept the other reply as it has more options, thank you Barmar!